# Microsoft Edge : Cross zone connection error

Tags: websocket, microsoft-edge, loopback

I have a script that uses WebSocket on loopback.
Edge shows the following error when script try to connect to 127.0.0.1:4530.

"SCRIPT12017: WebSocket Error: SECURITY_ERR, Cross zone connection not allowed"

Solution :
I have made the following changes and it worked for me.

- In the Control Panel - Internet Option, select the Security Tab. In the Security tab, select Local intranet zone. Click on Sites button and uncheck all checkboxes in Local intranet dialog.

I want to know :

1. what is the meaning of this error :
   "SCRIPT12017: WebSocket Error: SECURITY_ERR, Cross zone connection not allowed"
   and
2. why I have to make above changes in Internet options.

I have googled it but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a security-related error. It looks like your site is trying for making a connection through different security zones which is not allowed as per your settings.
2. When you modified the settings by unchecking the options in sites, now it is allowed for making a connection through different security zones which fixed that error.

Comment: @Munavvar, can you please inform the status of this issue? If above answer solved the issue, then please try to accept the answer. If you found the solution by yourself then try to post your solution as an answer. If the issue still persists then let us know about the current status for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.